# numpy error when running Python script from cmd

Tags: python, numpy, cmd

I have a Python script which I want to start from cmd because I'm going to call it in a C# script. 
The problem is, the code works fine in the IDE and when I call it from the Anaconda script but not when I call it from the regular cmd. 
I'm calling the script with the following line:

> $ python c:/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/main.py

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import process
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/process.py", line 4, in                                     <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/numpy/__init__.py", lin                                    e 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/numpy/add_newdocs.py",                                     line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/numpy/lib/__init__.py",                                     line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/numpy/lib/type_check.py                                    ", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/pycharmProjects/testing/numpy/core/__init__.py"                                    , line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray

I have uninstalled and reinstalled numpy, but the error is still the same. I'm really confused why I it works via the Anaconda prompt, but not the cmd as I did set the PATH variable.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: regular cmd? are you using a cygwin python version? note the cygdrive paths in traceback. On Windows you should use a native non-cygwin version